# PostgreSQL DB size increasing after restoring the same database backup

Tags: postgresql, restore

This is my batch script to take backup

`@ECHO OFF
d:
cd Apps\RemedyStar 9.0 KREMCOS\bin\Debug\PG
pg_dump.exe -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres  -F c -b -v -f "C:\Documents and Settings\GDS\Desktop\backup\RStar.backup" "RStar"
echo Backup Taken Complete 
pause`

using this script my backup method is correct

this is my batch script to restore

`cd /D D:\\Apps
cd RemedyStar 9.0 KREMCOS
cd bin
cd Debug
cd PG
pg_restore.exe -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres --dbname RStar  "C:\Documents and Settings\GDS\Desktop\backup\RStar.backup"
pause`

i'm trying to restore the same database, after restoring my db's size increasing

NOTE : i've already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052092/postgresql-db-size-increasing-after-restoring-the-same-database-backup) in stackoverflow

Comment: You should not cross-post your question. If you think it's better suited here, then ask SO to migrate it to SF.

Comment: Have you tried to run a vacuum process?

Comment: @Florin Asavoaie no

Comment: Well, try it! :)

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie [1] while restoring am getting [this warning](http://imageshack.com/a/img823/7460/hcav.jpg)    [2] before restoring my db size was 58MB after restoring the size gained as 70MB then i have done full vaccum now its size is 64MB

Comment: Maybe there is a difference in data count? Or perhaps it stores a transaction log of what happened during the restore.